# How do I even out a tile floor to properly support a dishwasher?

Tags: appliances, dishwasher

I'm remodeling my kitchen and I have tiles under the dishwasher. Unfortunately the transition between tiles is not even and 2 tiles are lapping EXACTLY where the dishwasher back wheel is. This makes the dishwasher unstable.

I was thinking that there must be a floor mat out there that I can use that will even out the irregularities? This will have the added benefit of reducing vibrations as well. I made an extensive web search for such mats but I just can't find anything specifically made for dishwashers. I know there are mats out there for washing machines and driers but not dishwashers.

Actually that's not entirely true, there is this one sketchy website that sells some floor mat for dishwasher for an awful lot of money (like $80 for a 24x24 mat). Is there no reasonable alternative that I can find in some retail store? Would a washing machine mat work, provided it's not too thick (dishwasher is under the counter) and rather firm (can't allow for bouncing as dishwasher will be screwed under the counter I think)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Most" kitchen appliances have adjustable feet that "should" be able to adjust to take up a 2-3" difference in flooring heights.  Your other option is to measure the difference and fill the gap with an appropriately width piece of plywood.

Check out this Image I found on http://www.dannylipford.com/how-to-install-a-dishwasher/
[image: Plumb and level it by raising and lowering the adjustable feet on either side.]

Comment: I know about the feet. Like I said the feet fall right in between the tiles. But I will use plywood and that seems quite stable.